# smoke effect in the ogre3d

Tags: iphone, ogre3d

I am working the particle effects in ogre3d for iphone

```
 Ogre::ParticleSystem*  sunParticle = OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pSceneMgr-   >createParticleSystem("Smoke", "Examples/Smoke");
sunParticle = OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pSceneMgr->createParticleSystem("Smoke", "Examples/Smoke");
 Ogre::SceneNode* particleNode = OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("Particle");
particleNode->attachObject(sunParticle);
```

This is my plugin code

```
# Defines plugins to load

# Define plugin folder
PluginFolder=./

 # Define plugins
Plugin=RenderSystem_GL
 Plugin=Plugin_ParticleFX
```

In staticloader also contains this installing manually

```
 #ifdef OGRE_STATIC_ParticleFX
     mParticleFXPlugin = OGRE_NEW ParticleFXPlugin();
     root.installPlugin(Plugin_ParticleFX);
        root.loadPlugin(mParticleFXPlugin);
```

## endif

I have also add the .particle file
I think i followed all the steps 
**An exception has occurred: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Cannot find required template 'Examples/Smoke' in ParticleSystemManager::createSystem at /Users/davidrogers/Documents/Ogre/ogre-v1-7/OgreMain/src/OgreParticleSystemManager.cpp (line 327)
2012-03-22 14:06:46.757 iphonesampleOgreapp[23041:207] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the resource folder(s), too, to be able to use the actual particle scripts. Are you absolutely sure you do this correctly?

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Basic+Tutorial+6&structure=Tutorials#Resources).

I really think that this error message sounds like the ressources are not correctly initialized or -if they are- the particle script is simply erroneous.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i have added in the particle scripts file in the resources.cfg also ,